# Spring Controllers,Service Classes,HiberNate Dao Classes ? why no Exceptions at dao's,service classes?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I did'nt get proper understanding from existing answers I have fully form-based web-application in which i have one spring controller for each form.

common base-class having code of varible(singleton object) declaraion of all service class instances(to-avoid declaring bo member variable in every controller,for business sevices interaction),which is parent for all controllers.

Common base-class having code of variable(singleton object) declaration of all dao service instances,which is parent for all BO's classes.

Common base-class having code of variable(singleton object) declaration of HibernateTemplate,SessionFactory using @Autowired annotaions.Which is parent for all dao classes.One parent for all of above three classes which is having Logger object instances.

One fbisExceptionHandler.java which  captures exceptions from all @RequestMapping methods from all controllers as bellow

```
@ControllerAdvice  
                public class ExceptionControllerAdvice  
             {  
                @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)  
                public ModelAndView exception(Exception e)   
               {  
                                ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exception");  
                                mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());  
                                logger.error( e.getMessage())
                                mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());  
                                return mav;    
                }  
            }
```

please answer my questions
1) Is this single method fine for handling all exceptions .i,e those getting caught in controller,service classes,dao classes ?
2)why my all hibernate dao's methods not using either try..catch block or throws declaraion at methods signature....Is hibernate dao's did'nt throw any exception ? If so where they caught ?
for example one of my hibernate dao is
3)How all constarints from db vendors are handled ? Is there any hibernate inbuilt way ?
4) why my all my bo's methods not using either try..catch block or throws declaraion at methods signature.... where exactly exceptions being thrown and caught ?

```
My sample dao  

    package com.fbis.form18.daoimp;
        all imports 
        @Repository
        public class Form18daoImp implements Form18Dao{
            @Autowired
            SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
            @Autowired
            public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
            {
                this.hibernateTemplate=new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
            }
            public void save(Form18Dtls form18dtls) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(form18dtls);
                          logger.info("Form18Dtls saved successfully");
            }
            @Override
            public Form18Dtls findbyFacId(String facID) {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                List list=hibernateTemplate.find("from Form18Dtls where FAC_ID=?", facID);
                          logger.info("findbyFacId ran successfully");            
                return (Form18Dtls)list.get(0);
            }  
    all dao's methods are continued here..
    }


My sample bo

    package com.fbis.form18.boimp;
    all imports
    @Service("form18Bo")
    public class Form18boImp implements Form18Bo 
    {
        @Autowired
        Form18Dao form18dtlsdao;

        @Transactional
        public void save(Form18Dtls from18dtls) 
        {
            String UniqueTransactionNumber=getFacId(from18dtls.getFacDistrict(),"Form18_Dtls");
            from18dtls.setFacId(UniqueTransactionNumber);
            from18dtls.setSubmtdDate(new java.util.Date());
            from18dtls.setAppStatus("I");
            from18dtls.setFormId(23);
            form18dtlsdao.save(from18dtls);

        }
        public String getFacId(String district,String tableName)
        {
            FacIdGenerator facid=new FacIdGenerator();
            String genFacid=facid.factoryIdCreator("F18", district, tableName);
                logger.info("getFacId ran successfully");         
            return genFacid;

        }
        @Override
        public Form18Dtls findbyFacId(String facID) {
            return form18dtlsdao.findbyFacId(facID);
        }
    other bo's continued here
```

If i am following wrong heirarkey of classes,suggestions are welcome,Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Can any body answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question revolves around exceptions thrown from the data access layer, in this case you are using hibernate as your vendor.

If this is so then this is a pure java issue regarding checked exceptions and un-checked exceptions. Hibernate exceptions are un-checked (extend the RuntimeException) so there is no need to declare them on the method signatures and no need to catch them. On top of that, it is possible to tell Spring to transform specific vendor (e.g. hibernate) exceptions to Spring DataAccessException (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html).

Regarding your numbered questions above:

1. Yes
2. As I said, hibernate throws RuntimeExceptions, you do not need to declare them and if you do not catch them, then your @ExceptionHandler will catch them and handle them.
3. I don't understand the question
4. The same answer as in number 2